# Split up bonus inversely to errors

Tags: percentages

I have five teams, A-E, who have made errors as follows (errors are percentages):

```
A   30
B   20
C   12
D   22
E   16
```

I have to allocate a bonus of $50 in inverse proportion to their errors.

I initially tried a naive approach to allocate based on existing percentages, and then subtract that from 50, in which I ended up with a bonus distribution of 200 against 50, which is obviously not feasible.

My current approach is to take `1/Percentage`, then take the percentage of each team's inverse over the total, and use that to split up the $50, which gives me:

```
    Score   Point   Adjusted    Adjusted Percent    Allocation
A   30      0.3     3.3333333   0.1213793103        6.068965517
B   20      0.2     5           0.1820685           9.103448276
C   12      0.12    8.3333333   0.3034482759        15.17241379
D   22      0.22    4.5454545   0.1655172414        8.275862069
E   16      0.16    6.25        0.2275862069        11.37931034
```

Now, this works, and does give me something that feels right, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach to splitting up the bonus.

This is not a homework problem, or one I found in a textbook, so I don't have a solution or topic based hint to check against.